# How to include new line a string variable

Tags: php

from file_get_contents() I got a string with no new lines (\n). By adding "pre" tag I can see the nice format. Now from that nice format, I need to include this new line character so I can explode() it to arrays. How can I do that? Sample data with pre like below:

```
S,1,R:M,2,R:L,3,R:XL,4,R:2XL,5,X
Soft Black,1,D:Forest Green,2,D:Grey,3,L:Navy,4,D:Red,5,D:Royal Blue,6,D:Sport Grey,7,L
R,D,8.50:X,D,10.52:R,L,7.91:X,L,9.97:R,N,7.02:X,N,8.64
1:1:13,32,44,82,20
```

Without pre becomes:

S,1,R:M,2,R:L,3,R:XL,4,R:2XL,5,X
Soft Black,1,D:Forest Green,2,D:Grey,3,L:Navy,4,D:Red,5,D:Royal Blue,6,D:Sport Grey,7,L
R,D,8.50:X,D,10.52:R,L,7.91:X,L,9.97:R,N,7.02:X,N,8.64
1:1:13,32,44,82,20

Comment: If it is correctly formatted with pre tags there *are* new lines in the data

Comment: But explode('\n',$file) still returns one array which tells me there is no \n character.

Comment: Inspect the source string. Those line breaks aren't there by magic when putting it in a `pre` tag

Comment: Also `'\n'` doesn't match linebreaks. You want `""`.

Comment: View Source shows nothing. How to inspect the source string?

Comment: I can't use space as delimiter because there is space used in the data.

Comment: Space? What space? I am talking about using double quotes instead of single quotes. Please read the related section in our fine manual about the difference between the two http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: I tried with " ", it returns wrong arrays.

Comment: In that case first read the manual about [`explode()`](http://nl3.php.net/explode) so you know why it does that after that you can fix it by reading the manual previously linked on how to fix ti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not many solutions...
Try this :

```
<?php
...
$line = nl2br( $file ) ;
echo $line ;
...
?>
```

If the format is good in html (Without pre becomes) you try "explode()" with one of this delemiter :

- `"\r\n"`
- `"\n\r"`
- `"\n"`
- `"\r"`

Comment: Thank you. The nl2br almost there. I see the br element, but explode("<br>",$file) still returns one array. The other delimiters also return one array.